# Spring entities and business logic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design

I am developing a spring application, where I have three layers as most of other spring apps. The Rest Controllers on front, Services in middle, and JPA repositories in behind. Now we have spring entities mapped to the db, in my case they are plain old java objects(POJO), with only some fields and getters and setters which I usually prefer and don't want to put any business logic in there. However, in this project, I find out that in a lot of services I am repeating the same piece of code, something like that

```
User user=userRepository.findUserByName("some name here");
if(user==null){
   throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");
}
```

Now, this is not only for a single entity, there are many other similar repeated parts too. So, I have started to worry about it and looking possible areas to push that code and eliminate the repeated parts. One thing makes sens as stated in domain driven design, put that business logic inside the entity, now they will have both data and part of business logic. Is that a common practice?

Comment: This is a too broad question, you are basically asking what are the pros and cons of applying DDD.

Comment: Yeah, this is too bread. I am going to narrow down it, is that a common practice to put part of your business logic in entity classes while keeping the bulk in services?

Comment: In general, you put the logic for the writing/updating in the entity and logic for finding inside the repository. In `CQRS` this is very explicit (by definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much looks like a simple code reuse problem. If you are always throwing the same exception in all contexts then what about implementing a `findExistingUserByName` method on the repository that throws if the user doesn't exist?

Your code would become:

```
User user = userRepository.findExistingUserByName("username");
```

If you do not want to change the repository contract you could also implement a `UserFinderService` at the application level which wraps over a `UserRepository` and provides that service-level behavior.

Another more generic idea could be to implement a generic method and make it available to your application services either by inheritance, composition or a static class which would allow you to do something like:

```
withExistingAggregate<User>(userRepository.findUserByName("username"), (User user) -> ...)
```

Comment: Good points thank you very much, but what about putting it in entity itself? What is the common practice ? What can be broken if I put business logic in entity classes?

Comment: I'm not sure that I see how you could put that logic into the entity, given that if no user is found then none gets instantiated. Do you mean encapsulating that logic within a `static` method on the `User` class? That would violate the single responsibility principle and wouldn't be cohesive at all. The `User` class is meant to be the abstraction for a user concept, not an abstraction for the storage and retrieval of users (which is the role of the repository already).

Comment: Some could further argue that throwing an exception when a user is not found is an application-level concern because it has to do with the workflow. If you adhere to that way of thinking then you would also avoid putting that logic into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You cat return `Optional<User>` from repository in this and similar cases.
Then you service code will look like:

```
userRepository.findUserByName("some name here")
.ifPresent(user -> doThmsWithUser(user));
```

Comment: yes, but still I have to make an if check all over in my service classes and throw the exception. So, optional is not making life much easier.Simply for null, it was null check for optional, I need to check if value present. In either case it will end up with NPE for null or Value not present for Optional.

Comment: If you use `Optional` it throws NoSuchElementException instead of null value.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` you will get only in case if you trying to get something from empty `Optional`, in code above there is no `get`

Comment: Whether it is  NoSuchElementException or NullPointerException, does it change anything? You did not get the question. Still I have to make an if check in all of my service classes.

Comment: I agree, that doesn't solve the question's problem, although the contract is cleaner with `Optional` so I'd use it still for that purpose.